# What is the word for mourning something you never had?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for mourning something you never had? I'm looking for a word similar to "Schadenfreude" or "Sonder" in that it represents a very specific emotion. You dont get this feeling from an event, but rather from the implications of it. Say for example, your only sibling dies. This feeling comes from realizing you will never be an aunt/uncle, or from realizing you will have to organize your parents' funerals without your sibling's help. You are mourning the kinds of things you didnt know could be taken away from you. Anyone have a word for this emotion?

Comment: This is too obvious to be believable.  But note than SWRs require some research; I'd recommend Google NGram; the other requirement is the requested word as a blank in a sentence.

Comment: maybe something like 'clear-eyed'

Comment: it's use can be found in many books but no suggestions of an alternative single word ... at least in English

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A word that means "nostalgia for an experience that I did not have."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/352785/a-word-that-means-nostalgia-for-an-experience-that-i-did-not-have)

Comment: From the answers [there](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/352785/142322): consider [*wistful*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/352799/142322).

Comment: Regret is the word that might fit.

Comment: Judges 11:37 (Jephtha's daughter) is about a _lament_. She lamented that she had never had a child.

Comment: related: [Is there a word for “What might have been”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287290/is-there-a-word-for-what-might-have-been)

Comment: For the OP: Take a look at this Wikipedia article on [“saudade.”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade) It might answer your question.

Comment: Mourning **for**, or, perhaps better, grieving **over**. And if you want a German word, surely you are posting to the wrong list.

Answer (score 1):

Though a bit broad, the word "melancholia" or "melancholy" can be defined as of a feeling sadness, mournfulness or lamenting with no obvious reason. I think that can include reasons never fulfilled or experienced - deeply rooted unrealized experiences.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/melancholia

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for an answer to this very question.  I frequently feel this when looking at old photos of people I never met.  A sort of grief over the loss of person/place/time period I never experienced and am fully aware that I am probably romanticizing. There seem to be several words which swerve near it, but fail to hit the mark. Hiraeth and Saudade each come close with elements of Weltschmerz and Wabi-sabi (which is not an emotion, but an ascetic; but if the ascetic WERE an emotion, it would fit) thrown in.  In researching, I came across this post: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/nostalgia-for-a-place-or-time-youve-never-been-to.1898243/
in which user EStjarn posits Paranostalia as a good potential fit for a newly coined word to mean this, and I agree.

Comment: After posting this, I came across: Anemoia: Nostalgia For A Time You’ve Never Known- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wH6ZCIRjI14
which seems to be someone else's attempt to name the same feeling.

Answer (score 0):

Hiraeth? - a Welsh word that has no direct translation

According to Wikipedia, the closest available English translation is homesickness or nostalgia.

> Hiraeth (pronounced [hiraɪ̯θ][1]) is a Welsh word which means
>   'nostalgia', or, more commonly, 'homesickness'. Many Welsh people
>   claim 'hiraeth' is a word which cannot be translated, meaning more
>   than solely "missing something" or "missing home." To some, it implies
>   the meaning of missing a time, an era, or a person. It is associated
>   with the bittersweet memory of missing something or someone, while
>   being grateful of that/ their existence. Hiraeth bears considerable
>   similarities with the Portuguese concept of saudade (a key theme in
>   Fado music), Galician morriña, Romanian dor, Russian toska (тоска),
>   German Sehnsucht and Ethiopian tizita (ትዝታ).

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiraeth

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage.  We like to see answers with solid explanations and authoritative references.  Perhaps you could edit your answer to provide more detail and some links to support it?  Also, you might want to [take the site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through [the help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Bit annoying that it has no direct translation in English! Could you suggest some English words instead?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be

**Sorrow** which covers both a sense of loss of the subject and the consequences thereof. As defined in 1b from [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sorrow)

> 1a : deep distress, sadness, or regret especially for the loss of someone or something loved
>    b : resultant unhappy or unpleasant state
>     //to their great sorrow they could not marry

I agree the dictionary definition is not a good context for the question so given the above.

> For example, your only sibling dies. This **sorrow** comes from
>   realizing you will never be an aunt/uncle.